# History of Dihedral Groups?

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, math-history, dihedral-groups

I'm trying to write a brief historical outline for a project concerning Dihedral Groups, but It has been to hard for me to find information about the first time these groups appeared on literature. If you know where and in which context they first appeared it would be highly helpful. By the way, the oldest reference of Dihedral Groups I've found is in the Burnside's book "Theory of groups of finite order" (Pp. 377) published in 1897.

Answer (score 1):

Felix Klein (1884) in the German original of his "Lectures on the Icosahedron" describes the dihedral groups as the rotation groups of dihedra and uses the phrase "Diedergruppe", which is the German for dihedral group. In more detail:

- [p. 9](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN516762672?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B17%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%7D): Section heading "Die Gruppe der Diederdrehungen" [The rotation group of a dihedron]
- [p. 10](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN516762672?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B18%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%7D): "Ausser den hiermit aufgezählten Drehungen umfasst die Diedergruppe keine anderen." [In addition to the ones that we have just enumerated, the dihedral group contains no more rotations.]
- Sometimes he writes "Dieder-Gruppen" instead of "Diedergruppen", both meaning "dihedral groups". E.g. on [p. 27](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN516762672?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B35%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%7D).

My starting point was a remark by [Renate Tobies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renate_Tobies) in her [Klein biography](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-75785-4): on p. 143 she mentions three 1874-75 papers by Klein in the Erlanger Sitzungsberichte, subsequently expanded for publication in Mathematische Annalen. I have NOT tracked any of these down yet, partially because her remark "later, he added the dihedron" means that we aren't guaranteed to find the dihedral groups there.

Note that the term "dihedral" itself is much older: [MacTutor](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathword/d/) documents its being used in 1799.